# Sqlite, UPDATE with JOINs with 3 tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, multiple-tables

I want to change a value in SQLite. Unfortunately I am a beginner. 
To get that value I have 3 IDs (COMPANY.CompanyID, EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID, TELNUMBER.CountryID). I know that every employee has just one number for each country.
I don't know how to make that UPDATE-Statement. I tried a lot but still not working. I tried something like that but I its wrong (here he changed three rows instead one):

```
--SELECT * FROM TELNUMBER
UPDATE TELNUMBER
SET Value = '123456789'
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT EMPLOYEE.CompanyID
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID = TELNUMBER.EmplyeeID
    AND(
        SELECT COMPANY.CompanyID
        FROM COMPANY
        WHERE COMPANY.CompanyID = EMPLOYEE.CompanyID))
AND TELNUMBER.CountryID = '3' -- here more filter ??
```

I want to change:

- TELNUMBER.Value = 123456789

I have just that values:

- COMPANY.CompanyID = '102'
- EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID = '1003'
- TELNUMBER.CountryID = '3'

```
SELECT * FROM TELNUMBER
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID = TELNUMBER.EmplyeeID
LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON COMPANY.CompanyID = EMPLOYEE.CompanyID
WHERE COMPANY.CompanyID = '102' AND EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID = '1003' AND TELNUMBER.CountryID = '3'
```

Hope someone could help me.

```
CompanyID   Company
101         XXY
102         AAAA


EmployeeID  CompanyID   CompanyName
1001        101         XXY
1005        101         XXY
1006        101         XXY
1007        101         XXY
1008        102         AAAA
1009        102         AAAA
1010        101         XXY
1004        101         XXY
1002        102         AAAA
1003        102         AAAA


NumberID    EmplyeeID   Value   CountryID
5001        1001        1111111 1
5002        1002        2222222 2
5003        1001        3333333 3
5004        1001        4444444 5
5005        1003        5555555 4
5006        1002        6666666 1
5007        1001        7777777 6
5008        1003        8888888 2
5009        1009        99999   3
5010        1003        1212121 1
5011        1005        1201235 2
5012        1007        988966  1
5013        1003        8888888 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TELNUMBER SET Value = '123456789' WHERE NumberId = 
(SELECT NumberId FROM TELNUMBER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON TELNUMBER.EmployeeID = EMPLOYEE.EmployeeID 
WHERE TELNUMBER.EmployeeID = '1003' AND TELNUMBER.CountryID = '3' and EMPLOYEE.CompanyID = '102');
```

There is no need to JOIN COMPANY table, since CompanyID is already present in EMPLOYEE.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works! I use other additional IDs, that example is just the short version. I know is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not allow direct joins in the UPDATE statement, but you can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE TELNUMBER
SET Value = '123456789'
WHERE EmployeeID = 1003 AND CountryID = 3
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Employee e 
  WHERE e.EmployeeID = TELNUMBER.EmployeeID AND e.CompanyID = 102
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qQE8CVd7zxM9qYwhPYmyoP/2).

Results:

```
| NumberID | EmployeeID | Value     | CountryID |
| -------- | ---------- | --------- | --------- |
| 5001     | 1001       | 1111111   | 1         |
| 5002     | 1002       | 2222222   | 2         |
| 5003     | 1001       | 3333333   | 3         |
| 5004     | 1001       | 4444444   | 5         |
| 5005     | 1003       | 5555555   | 4         |
| 5006     | 1002       | 6666666   | 1         |
| 5007     | 1001       | 7777777   | 6         |
| 5008     | 1003       | 8888888   | 2         |
| 5009     | 1009       | 99999     | 3         |
| 5010     | 1003       | 1212121   | 1         |
| 5011     | 1005       | 1201235   | 2         |
| 5012     | 1007       | 988966    | 1         |
| 5013     | 1003       | 123456789 | 3         |
```

But I'm not sure why you need the condition `CompanyID = 102`. It seems like in the table `TELNUMBER` the combination of `EmployeeID` and `CountryID` is unique.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! It wokrs!
Is not unique in my real database. That is just an example similar to that but shorter.

Comment: I just clicked to check what happen, is my second topic by stackoverflow. I would to accept both answers but I can choose just one.

Comment: Yes, just choose 1 that you will use.